# .htaccess for angular html5 redirect not working

Tags: angularjs, html, apache, .htaccess

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

is placed within the root dir (alongside index.html). However, when I do a refresh, I get the error: `The requested URL <url> was not found on this server`.
The same url is working from within the app link. Is there something wrong with my `.htaccess` file ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

with the [`L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) above your `index.html` rule, so I'm guessing the `index.html` rule doesn't even get processed. Not to mention, the `^.*$` rule does not seem well formed as there is [no rewrite URL/URI specified](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). Instead, it seems you are rewriting all requests to a dash (`-`).

Change the file to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule .* /index.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, can you please paste the correct .htaccess file contents ?

Comment: Try taking off the `QSA` flag and also see if you have any `AllowOverride None` directives in your .conf files in the `/etc/apache2` folder.

Comment: I have this tag in my http.conf file : <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Still not working...

Comment: That directive is a good thing to check the config files for, because it will cause Apache to ignore your .htaccess files and use the rewrite rules in the config files instead.